# Why does my JFrame not show my label

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jlabel

I have this loadpanel to show to the user when my program is exporting the video. So when the export button is clicked, I do this:

```
loadframe = new LoadFrame("Video Exporteren...");
```

This creates the dialog and shows it on the screen. Yet, it takes about 5 seconds before the actual label on the dialog is shown. Can  anyone tell me why.
Thanks

```
public LoadFrame(String operation) {

    mainloadframe = new JDialog();
    JLabel operationlabel = new JLabel(operation);
    loadpanel = new JPanel();

    mainloadframe.setSize(300, 75);
    mainloadframe.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    mainloadframe.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
    mainloadframe.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
    mainloadframe.setTitle(operation);
    mainloadframe.setResizable(false);

    loadpanel.add(operationlabel);
    mainloadframe.add(loadpanel);
    mainloadframe.setVisible(true);

}
```

Comment: Are you executing anything else after showing the dialog? It sounds like you might be blocking the EDT

Comment: The code itself works fine, it would suggest you are performing a block or time consuming operation, after trying to show the dialog, within the EDT

Comment: Yeah I am exporting a video, wich is relatively time/memory consuming

Comment: I've added answer, I hope it addresses you problems

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Swing uses a single thread model.  This means that interactions with the UI (create/modify) are executed within a single thread, known as the Event Dispatching Thread.

The `RepaintManager` uses the EDT to schedule repaint requests.  If something blocks the EDT, these paint requests (and other events) won't be processed.

Swing is also not thread safe.  This means you are expected to create and modify the UI only from within the context EDT.

The problem you have, is you are blocking the EDT with a time consuming process, meaning that the EDT can't process any events until your long-running task is complete.

There are a number of solutions.

### You Could...

Use a background thread to perform the time consuming operation.  This leads to the next problem of how to you tell the UI when something has changed (ie, provide progress updates or that the process has completed).

You could use `SwingUtilities.invokeLater` to re-sync updates with UI.  This places a `Runnable` onto the EDT, ensuring that the `run` method is executed within in the context of the EDT.

### You Could...

Use a `SwingWorker`.  A `SwingWorker` has methods to automatically re-sync with EDT, allowing you to `publish`/`process` changes within the EDT as well as a `done` method which is executed within the context of the EDT after its `doInBackground` method completes.

This is probably the simplest to the methods as it all nicely self contained.

Check out [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details

Comment: Thank you very much, that knowledge will definitely help me here :)

Answer (score 2):

You miss this line:

```
mainloadframe.pack();
```

Also:

- Make sure that `LoadFrame()` is invoked from the EDT.
- Use `loadFrame()` for the method name instead of `LoadFrame()`.

Comment: `pack` shouldn't make any difference (while it's not a bad idea), the OP has already set the size of the frame and `setVisible` should invalidate the container...

Answer (score 1):

```
mainloadframe.add(loadpanel);
```

should be

```
mainloadframe.setContentPane(loadpanel);
```

Comment: FYI As of Java 5 `Window#add` defers to `Window#getContentPane().add`

Answer (score 0):

mainloadframe.add(loadpanel);

should be

mainloadframe.getContentPane(loadpanel);

Comment: FYI As of Java 5 `Window#add` defers to `Window#getContentPane().add`