# JLabel saying "please wait" not running

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jlabel

I'm trying to make a java app and after using Swing to get some input data from the user I begin to run the main computational chunk of my program (not the main method just to be clear). While this method is running I'd like to display something along the lines of "Please wait... dont touch anything" However, the problem is that the JPanel I'm using to display this goes completely black for the duration of the method which is doing the calculations is running. I've tried to print the JLabel.getText() in the middle of the method and it comes out as it is supposed to. Any idea as to why the text will not appear. Below is my code.

```
JFrame toDisplay = new JFrame("Please Wait");
  toDisplay.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
  toDisplay.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  toDisplay.setVisible(true);
  toDisplay.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
  toDisplay.setSize(300,200);
  toDisplay.setLocation((int)dimension.getWidth()/3, (int)dimension.getHeight()/3);

  JLabel message = new JLabel("<html>CheapTix is currently running<br /> please do not close this box or open the file <br /> Destinations.txt <br /> until instructed to do so</html>");
  toDisplay.add(message,BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

This is followed by the main bulk of my program running. I have tried putting the toDisplay.add(message) inside of the main portion of my program but this did not seem to work either.
Any help would me much appreciated.

Comment: Check out [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16810121/why-does-my-jframe-not-show-my-label/16825813#16825813) for a possible solution

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is due to Swing concurrency. You're running a long-running process on the Swing event thread, and this prevents the event thread from painting.  The solution: use a background thread such as a SwingWorker.

For more on this, please see [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/)

Also,

```
JFrame toDisplay = new JFrame("Please Wait");
  toDisplay.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
  toDisplay.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  toDisplay.setVisible(true);
  toDisplay.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
  toDisplay.setSize(300,200);
  toDisplay.setLocation((int)dimension.getWidth()/3, (int)dimension.getHeight()/3);

  JLabel message = new JLabel("<html>CheapTix is currently running<br /> 
      please do not close this box or open the file <br /> 
      Destinations.txt <br /> 
      until instructed to do so</html>");
  toDisplay.add(message,BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

- This looks as if you're displaying a secondary window as a JFrame which is not a good idea. Instead use a JDialog.
- Don't set the size of components, but rather let them size themselves.

Comment: Great thank you, what I dont understand though is since my method takes inputs from the user how can I use the doInBackGround() method which takes no parameters?

Comment: @DavidR: The parameters can be passed into the SwingWorker via a constructor that you give to the SwingWorker class.

Comment: I finally got it to work! I'd be lying if I told you I understood it but thank you for your help. Could you please clarify your edits. I don't understand what a secondary window as a JFrame means, also when I do not set the size of my components they end up tiny and I have to manually expand them to see their content.

Comment: @DavidR: If you are creating a dialog window, a window that is launched from a parent window, then it as a child of the parent is dependent on the parent and shouldn't be a JFrame but rather a JDialog since the dialog has mechanism for recognizing its parent and won't accidentally close the parent if it is closed.